# How to chain promises together

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I'm trying to get a value from a promise and then use that value to resolve another promise.

Without `rxjs` it works like this:

```
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(value => Promise.resolve(value + 1))
  .then(value => console.log(value))
```

output: 
`2`

---

Here's where I'm stuck with `rxjs`:

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(1))
  .map(value => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(value + 1));
  })
const observer = value => console.log(value);
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

output:

```
PromiseObservable {
_isScalar: false,
promise: Promise { 2 },
scheduler: undefined }
```

Comment: Replace `map` with `concatMap`, but this seems like a strange thing to be doing.

Comment: It definitely seems strange, but I’m assuming (or hoping) that the actual use case involves actually promises that are not statically resolved, so there is an actual reason to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`observable.map()` is supposed to transform the observed *value* into a different *value*. If you return an observable there, you transformed your value into an observable, so of course you will not get a value back. Essentially you turned your observable of values into an observable of observables of values.

You will need to use the [`concatMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap) operator (also commonly known as [`flatMap`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)) instead if you want to return an observable and “unpack” that:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(1))
    .concatMap(value => {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(value + 1));
    })
    .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
// logs out 2
```

Comment: good sir, thank you for your time and knowledge! You're the best! I love you!

Comment: Actually, be aware that `concatMap()` and `flatMap()` (in RxJS 5 renamed to `mergeMap()`) are two very different things. However, in this demo it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Remember, Promises are Monads, meaning they implement a `flatMap`, which is disguised by `.then()`. When using RxJS you have to flatten stuff yourself:

```js
const observable = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(1))
  .switchMap(value => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(value + 1));
  })
const observer = value => console.log(value);
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

**tl;dr;** `fromPromise` returns an Observable of Observables. This is why you have to flatten the result.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)